# Is Identity Server 4 NIST compliant?

Tags: identityserver4

We have a set of applications consisting of Asp.Net MVC websites, Single page applications and Asp.Net Web APIs. We're planning to use Identity Server 4 to secure them. But before we proceed, we want to know whether it's NIST complaint or not? Will it create any issue during security audit?